# Receiving this error 'Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with nonzero exit code' when building a Python/Kivy app in Xcode10.1

Tags: python, kivy, xcode10.1

I coded an app in Python and kivy and it works well in PyCharm and I tried to convert it into an actual Mac app through Xcode 10.1. When I build and run the code to get the simulation, the building fails and I get this error. I assume that the TypeError is the issue. Inside my code, I have SQL queries, so I've removed the comma and added '%' instead. When a tuple is called to fill in the variables, it doesn't work. Maybe it is not the error after all?! Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a simple case like (or similar):

```
print ("The area of your shape is: ", (a*b))
#                                   ^
```

You forgot a comma.

Or, you may have a variable named `str`.

If you're still unable to solve then try a `Trial & Error` method to scrutinize where exactly the error may be stemming from, i.e. delete/comment out code that you think could be the root cause of this and you will eventually locate it.

Comment: Thank you AzyCrw4282! It didn't cross my mind that I could have forgotten a comma since my code was working well before.